# Angularjs controller not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As I felt my single controller was growing too large I am now trying to make use of multiple controllers. However, my UserController can't be found for some reason when I navigate to `/signup`. I'm getting this error:

**Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'UserController' is not a function, got undefined**

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngResource',
    'myApp.controllers',
]);

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('signup', {
      url: '/signup',
      templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
      controller: "UserController"
    });

});
```

I'm including the `.js` files in this order:

```
<script src="angular/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script> //binded to body tag
<script src="angular/controllers/userCtrl.js"></script> //set in signup state
<script src="angular/app.js"></script>
```

**UserController**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('UserController', function () {

  //do stuff

});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it easier on yourself and create cleaner code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngResource',
    'myApp.controllers',
])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('signup', {
      url: '/signup',
      templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
      controller: "UserController"
    });
});
```

you weren't using $urlRoutProvider and $httpProvider so why inject them?

Angular Modules are good for nothing...so far. Except for loading 3rd-party angular code into your app and mocking during testing. Other than that, there is no reason to use more than one module in your app.

To create your UserController do a

```
app.controller('UserController', function ($scope) {

  //do stuff

});
```

Comment: I am using `$urlRouteProvider` and `$httpProvider` but I have only included an extract of the code for the question.

Comment: Where do you intend that `app.controller` code go exactly?

Comment: In this particular case it would go into /controllers/userCtrl.js

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="angular/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script> //binded to body tag
<script src="angular/controllers/userCtrl.js"></script> //set in signup state
<script src="angular/app.js"></script>
```

You cant use a module before it's declared.so switch the scripts order.

You should stick to 1 independent module declaration per file and you'll be fine,otherwise you'll have to manage script order.

Comment: Thanks - it would be nice to know which order you actually mean but i tried putting app.js first but still the same problem

Comment: I think I've found the cause. There is something wrong in my taskCtrl file.

Answer (score -2):

Your app.js has to be declared first like below BEFORE you pull in its controller subcomponents:

```
<script src="angular/app.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script> //binded to body tag
    <script src="angular/controllers/userCtrl.js"></script> //set in signup state
```

Comment: This question is more than 1 year old.  If you intend to offer an answer to an old question like this, you should take extra care to ensure that the answer will provide value to future readers, and not just copy and paste an existing answer.

Comment: I didn't just copy and paste any answer; this is how I solved this problem for myself. Point taken on value for future readers however.